# Extended information for nodes in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

**I want to add more information to node/computer/agent entries in Jenkins (listed under <JenkinsUrl>/computer).**

minimum for me would be:

- URL to a wiki page (clickable)

and optimal would be in addition:

- more configurable columns / fields with different types possible

  - URL
  - HTML
  - Text
- above fields should be displayed in node/computer overview

Is this configurable in jenkins or are there plugins for that?

**Motivation**:

We have multiple teams sharing the same Jenkins instance and want to describe some maintenance details accessible from the jenkins node overview (e.g.: who is responsible for maintenance? Where is it hosted? How to get access?).

Comment: You can add all this information in the Node's description field. It also supports safe HTML (if you enabled that) so you can customize the look and feel of it.

Comment: @NoamHelmer Where can this be enabled? (To make sure, we're talking about the same stuff: I am looking at the Node overview at `<JenkinsUrl>/computer/` - see https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/nodes/

Comment: My bad, the main page doesn't have a description option, only the individual agent pages have the description filed.

Comment: @NoamHelmer thanks. rendering the description as HTML would suffice as minimal solution. Currently I see an unrendered description "Agent example-node (Some description <a href="https://google.com">some link</a>)"